# Cant figure out the way compiler does the calculation

Tags: c

Given is a C code, in which i am trying to figure out how the calculation order would go, well i thought it should be 3/2 first and then *5 or the other way round. But it gives an unexpected output of

> 5.000000

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    float a = 3/2*5;
    printf("%f", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is expected.

It calcuates 3/2 first (as integer), which is truncated down to 1. Then it multiplies by 5.

Try casting the numbers to (float) in your calculation - then you'll get the expected answer.

As suggested by damienfrancois, you can also get the compiler to treat them as floating point numbers as follows:

```
float a = 3.0/2.0*5;
```

In general, if you don't give any indication otherwise (such as the .0, or a cast), the compiler will treat numbers as an integer

Comment: does it always calculate as integer if we dont typecast?

Comment: @DakshShah: no it does not. It is cast to the first type in which the value will *fit*: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal (under "The type of a literal").

Comment: As I pointed out to others, why don't use `f` as these are floats and not doubles ? There's one redundant conversion.

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
float a = 3/2*5;
```

computes `a` as the integer division of 3 by 2, which is 1, then multiplied by 5 and cast to float.

Replace it with

```
double a = 3.0/2.0*5;
```

or

```
float a = 3.0f/2.0f*5;
```

and you'll get 7.500000

Comment: Maybe `f` suffix would be better as these are floats, not doubles

Comment: does it always calculate as integer if we dont typecast?

Comment: In C, a constant without decimal point is an integer. Any operation involving integers is an integer operation.

Comment: It may also be a `long`. The compiler will not complain if *intermediate* results are bigger than will fit in the target variable.

Answer (score 1):

It divides the integer 3 by integer 2, then multiplicates by integer 5, and then converts to a float.

Try `float a = 3.f/2*5;`

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication and division operator have equal precedence in evaluation. Since both operators are left to right associative, integer division (3/2) is performed first resulting in 1 and then followed by multiplication with 5.  Readup on operator associativity in C language

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence